# Adding CSS class to Html.BeginForm()

Tags: .net, css, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

How to add class attribute for following situation (Using ReturnUrl only):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
}
```

I want something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, new { @class = "login-form" })) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

There is an overload for that, if you supply the controller action, name, and form method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", 
            new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, 
            FormMethod.Post, new { @class="login-form" }))
{
  etc.
}
```

Comment: The most common use of the method is `Html.BeginForm()`, therefore, I wish Microsoft would make it possible to call `Html.BeginForm( new{ @class="something"})` without the need to care about all other parameters.

Comment: Agree it would be nice to only specify htmlAttribute, however you don't have to specify **all** the params, just the method: `Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "something" })`

Comment: What does the 3rd parameter do?

What's up with ReturnUrl?

Answer (score 1):

```cs
Html.BeginForm("Index", "EIApplication", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", **@class = "nea-forms"** })
```

Comment: Please add a comment explaining how your code fixes the issue to improve this answer.

Answer (score -3):

Or simply using html :

```
<form action="/ActionName/ControllerName" method="post" class="login-form">

</form>
```

Comment: The question specifically states *"Html.BeginForm()"*

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this will add the antiforgery token. Just something to keep in mind.