# Add a style attribute to Html.BeginForm MVC/C#

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller

Is it possible to add style attributes to a Html.BeginForm?

Something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {@class="myClass"}, new {@style="margin-right:100px margin-top:50px"}))
{
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding CSS class to Html.BeginForm()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984029/adding-css-class-to-html-beginform)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { style = "margin-right:100px; margin-top:50px", @class = "myClass"  }))
{

}
```

Comment: Always explain you code what you are giving. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Try this format
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null,FormMethod.Post, new { @style = "your styles ",@class = "your classname"}))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

[StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984029/adding-css-class-to-html-beginform)

[Another StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815762/how-can-i-apply-a-top-margin-to-my-html-beginform)

I'm not MVC expert, but according to attached links Your code should like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {@class="myClass"}, new {style="margin-right:100px margin-top:50px"}))
{
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { style = "margin-right:100px;margin-top:50px;border:1px solid red;", @class = "thFormClass" }))
{

}
```

Try this it will work.